# Jsrender how to reference loop index in a if clause

Tags: jsrender

I want to check for first pass of a for loop.  I have tried getIndex() and setting vars and both are not working.  What am I messing up?

```
{^{for samples}}
    {{setvar "itemIndex" #index+1 /}}  
    {{if ~getvar("itemIndex") = 0}}
      <input id="tab{{:#index+1}}" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
    {{else}}
      <input id="tab{{:#index+1}}" type="radio" name="tabs">
    {{/if}}
    <label for="tab{{:#index+1}}">{{:group}}</label>
{{/for}}

var vars = {};
    $.views.tags({
        setvar: function(key, value) {
            if (value) {
                vars[key] = value;
            } else {
                vars[key] = this.tagCtx.render();
            }
            return "";
        }
});

    $.views.helpers({
  getvar: function(key) {
    return vars[key];
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{if ~getvar("itemIndex") = 0}}` is a syntax error. Testing for equality to zero is `xxx === 0` or `xxx == 0`.

You should use a simple declarative approach, not try to use complex semi-programmatic setVar, getVar - which even if it worked would be unmaintainable...

Just write:

```
{^{for samples}}
  {{if #getIndex() === 0}}
    <input id="tab{{:#index+1}}" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  {{else}}
    <input id="tab{{:#index+1}}" type="radio" name="tabs">
  {{/if}}
  <label for="tab{{:#index+1}}">{{:group}}</label>
{{/for}}
```

Or if you prefer, simply `...{{if #index === 0}}...` or `...{{if !#index}}...`